# c++ create, assign and compare a new variable to two object inside an Operator Overloaded function

Tags: c++, oop

Apologize for my english. I'm trying to solve a very simple problem in c++. But i'm new in c++ so can't solve this :( 
I'm trying to use operator overloading with header files.  For new I'm trying to implementing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238216/c-create-assign-and-compare-a-new-variable-to-two-object-inside-an-operator-o) question. But I got error in getStatusPoint method.
[image]

```
int getStatusPoint(Alien const& alien)
{
    return alien.getHeight()*alien.getWeight()*aliean.getGender();
}

bool Alien::operator>(const Alien& alien) const {
    return(getStatusPoint(*this) > getStatusPoint(alien));
}
```

If I use don't use getStatusPoint method then its working fine.
Can anyone please help me to solve this question using getStatusPoint().

Comment: What does `getHeight()` return? Also `getWeight()` and `getGender()`? Could you please provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: Are your getter method declared as `const` ?  i.e. `int getWeight() const`

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error message suggests that neither getHeight nor getWeight is marked as const. You should define

```
class Alien ... {
public:
  int getHeight() const { ... }
  ...
};
```

Your implementation should neither write access to a field of your class nor call a non-const method of your class.

Comment: Is there any other way to create construction with :: and call it from main class?

Comment: I am not sure to understand, but you can also just declare the method _int getHeight() const;_ without any implementation in the class definition. At this point you can call it from the main class. You need then to provide the implementation in a .cpp file with _int Alien::getHeight() const { ... }_ The link edition will perform the connection.

Answer (score 2):

declare your `getHeight()`, `getWeight()` and `getGender()` as const like `int getHeight() const;`